# THREE.JS | Обновление атрибута шейдера

Tags: three.js, шейдеры, атрибуты, glsl

В приложении Three.JS, в mousemove есть небольшая проверка по ID.

if(id < N){

```
last_id = id;

for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){ if(i != (id)) { enabled[i] = 0.0; } }
points.geometry.attributes.enabled.needsUpdate = true;
```

}else if(id != last_id){

```
for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){  enabled[i] = 1.0; }
points.geometry.attributes.enabled.needsUpdate = true;
```

}

То есть эта часть должна обновить атрибут всем вершинам на 0, кроме той, которой присвоен id.

Но в результате, такое впечатление, что код выполняется не правильно, а точнее значения enabled не присваиваются немедленно, в mousemove, а где-то еще. Хотелось бы узнать, needsUpdate = true выполняет немедленно операцию и как можно поменять атрибут здесь и сейчас?

Если надо код, то http://vkuchinov.github.io/highlightShader/
Спасибо prisoner849 за основную часть кода.

Comment: За основу взят вот этот пример? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_instances_gpu.html

Comment: Скорее https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/1eafa293e7ce16b074a6d55cac67badc

Comment: Меня просто выбешивает тот факт, что я не понимаю, почему все равно идет подсветка не скольких элементов, при проверке enabled и 'обновлении' аттрибута здесь и сейчас.

Comment: Абсолютно точно needsUpdate не обновляет сразу аттрибуты

Answer (score 1):

Короче, если заменить здесь

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
...
if(id < N){

                highlight[id] = 1.0;
                points.geometry.attributes.highlight.needsUpdate = true;

            }
...

)};
```

**points.geometry.attributes.highlight.needsUpdate = true;**

На жесткое обновление

**points.geometry.addAttribute("highlight", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(highlight), 1));**

то все работает. Таким образом, имперически установлено, что needsUpdate тут не работает.

Comment: Кстати там еще была проблема с тем, что THREE.WebGLRenderTarget имел pixelRatio 1.0, в то время как renderer 2.0, из-за чего объект в WebGLRenderTarget был в два раза больше, соотвественно рядом пустые области выдавали цвет объекта при наведении.

Решалось это просто

        pickingTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio, window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio);

и
pickingTexture, event.clientX * window.devicePixelRatio, pickingTexture.height - event.clientY * window.devicePixelRatio,
            1, 1, pixelBuffer);